# find a counterexample of this statement of expression about the limit of composition function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, that $L\in U$ and that $h:U\setminus \left \{ L \right \}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ for some $p\in N$. If $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$ and $M=\lim_{y\rightarrow L}h(y)$. Then
$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(h\circ g)(x)=M$.

(Someone told me that this statement is false and should replace "$U\setminus \left \{ L \right \}$" with "$U$", and “$M=\lim_{y\rightarrow L}h(y)$. Then”
with “$h$ is continuous at $L$, then”.)

So can you give me a counterexample of the original statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is the following: Put
$$g(x):\equiv1\ ,\qquad h(y):=\cases{2\quad&$(y=1)$\cr 3&$(y\ne1)$\cr}\quad.$$
Then $h\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\equiv2$ and therefore $$\alpha:=\lim_{x\to0}h\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=2\ .$$ On the other hand the "inner limit" $\lim_{x\to0} g(x)=1$, and being careless one therefore would write
$$\alpha=\lim_{x\to0}h\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=\lim_{y\to1} h(y)=3\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $g(x)=L$ (constant), then $h(g(x))$ is not defined. If you suppose that $h$ is defined also in $L$, if it is not continuous you find:
$$
\lim_{x\to a} h(g(x)) = \lim_{x\to a} h(L) = h(L) \neq \lim_{y\to L} h(y)
$$

Comment: why not defined? Then $h(g(x))$ is just the value of $h$ by taking $L$ into the variable of $h$ and the statement still holds

Comment: because you are saying that $h$ has domain $U\setminus \{L\}$

Comment: I still don't get it. For example, let $h(x)=x$ but and $g(x)$ be a constant $L$ and h defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{ L \right \}$ but the statement still holds since $h(L)=\lim_{y\rightarrow L}h(y)$. I mean, though $h$ is not continuous at L but the limit is $h(L)$

Comment: You are correct, you should assume that $h(L) = \lim_{y\to L} h(y)$ in other words $h$ continuous at $L$ as you were told.

Comment: so what's a counterexample?

Comment: As in the answer, if $g$ is constant $L$ and $h$ is not continuous in $L$ you have a counterexample. Do you know an example of a non-continuous function?